# How to delete comments on LeanKit

Tags: leankit

We use LeanKit to manage our development tasks at work. Someone added a comment to a card that has nothing to do with the card. (They thought they were on a different card.)

We want to delete the comment, but there does not appear to be a way to do it. How can we do it, short of deleting the card and re-creating it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's currently not a way to delete a comment using the application itself, but the API supports deleting comments. You can use something like curl, [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), or [Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leankit-client) to script a DELETE of the comment.

You can see the API reference by going to:

https://{your-account}.leankit.com/io/docs/card/comment:delete